# Conda environment not detecting GPU in Google Colab

Tags: python, pytorch, anaconda, google-colaboratory

I'm installing a Conda environment in Google Colab but the GPU is not being detected even though Colab has a Tesla T4 GPU available.

In particular, when I run `import torch; print(torch.cuda.is_available())` it returns False while with the global python returns True

I'm installing Conda like this:

```
!pip install -q condacolab
import condacolab
condacolab.install()
```

These are my dependencies:

```
channels:
  - pytorch
  - nvidia
  - anaconda
dependencies:
  - python=3.10
  - matplotlib
  - seaborn
  - numpy
  - pytorch
  - torchvision
  - pytorch-cuda=11.8
  - pip:
    - pytorch-lightning
    - path
    - tensorguard
    - hydra-core
    - einops
  - pytest
  - tensorboard
  - tqdm
platforms:
  - linux-64
  - win-64
```

This is the nvidia-smi output:

```
Fri Aug 11 17:27:25 2023       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.105.17   Driver Version: 525.105.17   CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla T4            Off  | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   37C    P8    10W /  70W |      3MiB / 15360MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```